# How do I stop my program in Python using code?

Tags: python, exit

This is my code. I have searched on the internet for the answer but either I don't understand it, or it doesn't work for me. Please please please help me out and it will be really appreciated.

```
   sleep = input("Commander, would you like to sleep now? If yes then we can take out your bed. ")
if sleep == "yes":
    Energy = Energy + 5
    print("We have taken out your bed. The spaceship is on autopilot and you may now sleep.")
    time.sleep(4)
    print("2 weeks later...")
else:
    Energy = Energy - 5
    print("Ok. It is all your choice. BUT you WILL lose energy. Lets carry on with the journey. You have",Energy,"energy remaining.")
    time.sleep(4)
print("Commander, you have been extremely successful so far. Well done and keep it up!")
time.sleep(6)
direction = input("Oh no Sir! There is trouble ahead! Please make your decision quick. It's a matter of life and death. It is also a matter of chance! There are many asteroids ahead. You may either go forwards, backwards, left or right. Make your decision...before it's too late! ")  
if direction == "left":
    Coins = Coins + 15
    Fuel =  Fuel - 15
    while True:
        print ("You have managed to pass the asteroids, you may now carry on. You have",Fuel,"fuel left.")
        break
        continue
elif direction == "backwards":
    print("You have retreated and gone back to Earth. You will have to start your mission all over again.")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    print("The game will now restart.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Please wait...\n"*3)
    time.sleep(5)
    keep_playing = True
    while True:
         script()
elif direction == "forwards":
    Fails = Fails + 1
    print("You have crashed and passed away. Your bravery will always be remembered even if you did fail terribly. You have failed",Fails,"times.")
    time.sleep(3)
    ans = input("Do you want to play again? ")
    if ans == "yes":
        time.sleep(3)
        script()
    else:
        print("Our Earth is now an alien world...") 
        # Program stop here...
```

On the last line I want the program to stop: 
print("Our Earth is now an alien world...")

However, I know that there are ways to stop like `quit()`,`exit()`, `sys.exit()`, `os._exit()`. The thing is that `sys.exit()` stops the code but with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MEERJULHASH\Documents\lazy", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit()
SystemExit
```

On the other hand when I try to use the `os._exit()` on that last line line of code an error message comes up stating that `TypeError: _exit() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given).` `exit()` and `quit()` are not recommended for production code.

My question is that are there any exiting commands that stop your code from carrying on without showing any message or ending with `>>>` or that it just closes the program? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You want some kind of loop then. Loop the whole game (or parts) as many times as the user wish so, and break the loop after one run by default.

Comment: yes if that works. Sorry im new to python.

Comment: Yes then you need to learn about loops (like the `while` loop), do you know about it?

Comment: pls can you show me how to do that - very sorry

Comment: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/loops.html

Comment: I kind of know but i need to understand a bit better

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: i do understand while loops - just don't know how to use them in my case.

Comment: @wacraby  see my answer for a very rudimentary example.

Comment: please can someone edit my coding and fix it for me pls

Comment: It's not easy reading code with such long lines! You can break strings up into multiple parts & Python will automatically re-join them for you. Eg `print("this " "is " "a " "long " "string ")`. Each of those parts can go on a separate line.

Comment: @wacraby We can't really do that no, sorry. SO is not supposed, and wont, code for you. Try by yourself and come back here if you need it and did your own researches before doing so. Good luck.

Comment: can I use elif and a while loop at the same time

Comment: Try it & see what happens! If it doesn't work the way you expect, write a **small** example program to demonstrate the problem and ask a new question. See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you want to do, a simple option is to use a `while` loop.

Something similar to this (You'll have to adjust to your needs):

```
keep_playing = True

while keep_playing:
    print('Some actions...')

    if input('Do you want to keep playing? ') == 'no':
        keep_playing = False
        break
```

You may repeat your whole program or only parts of it. (depending on what you wrap with a `while` loop in such way)

The code I gave you here is very basic so you will need to adapt it.

Comment: def script():
    print ("you are dead")
    print ("hi")
    restart = raw_input("Would you like to restart this program? ")
    if restart == "yes":
        script()
    if restart == "no":
        print ("Script terminating. Goodbye.")

Comment: what is wrong with the script above?

Comment: @wacraby Don't put long code in the comment section or at least surround it by `` for proper styling. After creating your function, do you even call it? ( `script()`) The method you are using is a bit weird, you are using recursion instead of a simpler loop (it could work though).